# Make streachable image using resizableImageWithCapInsets

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I want to resize an image using resizableImageWithCapInsets method. But its not stretching. I also dont know the real funda of UIEdgeInsetsMake. Can any one tell me how it works.
I am using this code:

```
UIImage *mars = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png" ];
    UIImage* marsTiled = [mars resizableImageWithCapInsets:
                          UIEdgeInsetsMake(mars.size.height/4.0,
                                           mars.size.width/4.0,
                                           mars.size.height/4.0,
                                           mars.size.width/4.0)
                                              resizingMode: UIImageResizingModeStretch];

    [containerView addSubview:marsTiled];
```

Here container view is uiview.

[image: image to resize]
And it looks like after implement
[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
UIImage *rawEntryBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MessageEntryInputField.png"];
UIImage *entryBackground = [rawEntryBackground stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:13 topCapHeight:22];
UIImageView *entryImageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:entryBackground] autorelease];
entryImageView.frame = CGRectMake(5, 0, 248, 40);
entryImageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

Answer (score 0):

`UIEdgeInsets` lets you specify an area which will not be streched and therefor stay as it is. In your case you will probably want the image to be stretched in the middle of the circle and therefor have to specify the insets from the borders of your image to the middle of your circle with `UIEdgeInsetsMake()` by specifying the values for `top`, `left`, `bottom`, `right`. I would recommend using a tool like Photoshop or Preview and the marquee select function to determine the insets. Also you want to add an UIImageView to your containerView instead of the image directly.

[image]

```
[image resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(20.f, 12.f, 19.f, 19.f)]
```